# How do I force fortran to write four elements per line of a two dimensional array?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

Consider the following code. It writes "n" elements at a time. "n" was 5 for the intel compiler and "n" was 4 for pgi

```
         icels=128
         jcels=128
         imat=2 ! just for example
         write(ounit,*)
 x          ((real(pr(i,j,imat)),i=1,icels),j=1,jcels)
```

Where the "x" is a continuation character. I want the output to be formatted the same for both compilers. An example:

```
   6.2500001E-03   7.0312498E-03   7.8125000E-03   8.5937502E-03 
   9.3750004E-03   1.0156250E-02   1.0937500E-02   1.1718750E-02 
   .....
   .....
```

How do I replace the * with a correct format? Would prefer a fortran77 compliant answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the * with '(4(E13.6,1X))'  (including the quotes). This takes advantage of a Fortran feature called [format reversion](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/07/01/doctor-fortran-in-revert-revert-the-end-of-the-format-is-nigh).

I will note that your code is already not Fortran 77 compliant, so I am not sure why you are concerned about that.

Comment: Thanks. I've followed several of your posts on the intel forum. Anyways, I asked this question pre-maturely. Solved it myself